# PieCloudDB Database Roles and Privilege

Tags: security, user-roles

I create a ROLE1 in PieCloudDB Database, and I grant user1 and user2 in the same role, now if that same role has the privilege to write sql view in a shared schema, how do I prevent user1 to edit or delete the sql views created by user 2 and vice versa. Do I need to create individual role for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to create two different roles with the required set of privileges. PieCloudDB Database's access control system is designed based on the RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) model, If you assign the same role to different users, their privilege will be the same.